# Typescript - after checking if optional property exists on object still errors

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeBYAUFKYBOB7MA-AFxQCuAdgNbm4Du5A3OgL5NroDGu5AzsFLgBGAKxJxESVuk7c%20UADa4A5gHkRABTxgEUABRDRsKADJkWLSQrU65KMwCUCAHzJ0mLr1zyIAOkVL9ER8cfHs2KXY0Dzl-NWEAdQBLYAALTXwdQMMYR3gXVAwoRIAzPQNgrUcCzExYjS0ssLc7FgYgA)):

```
type T = {
  prop?: string;
};

const logObjProp = (obj: T & { prop: string }) => {
  console.log(obj.prop);
};

const logObjWithProp = (obj: T) => {
  if (obj.prop) {
    const { prop } = obj; // string
    logObjProp(obj); // Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  }
};
```

What I would expect that in the if block the type of `obj` becomes `T & { prop: string }` from `T`, because we checked if `prop` exists. But it's not the case. Why?

(Please don't get stuck in the example like "why don't you just pass `prop`". It doesn't make sense, but just to demonstrate the issue in the shortest way.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is narrowing non-discriminant inner property type doesn't change or narrow parent's type. `T` is not a union type that typescript can narrow. You may use `as` or [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to change the type:

```ts
const logObjWithProp = (obj: T) => {
  if (obj.prop) {
      logObjProp(obj as Required<T>);
// or logObjProp({ prop: obj.prop });
  }
};
```

Or define your `T` type with `prop` as [discriminant property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) like this:

```ts
type T = 
  | { prop: unknown } 
  | { prop?: never };

...
const logObjWithProp = (obj: T) => {
  if (obj.prop) {
    logObjProp(obj); // works as expected
  }
};
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w26Djw)